# Study the continuity of $f: (\mathbb{Z},\tau_i) \to (\mathbb{R}_+,\tau)$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}_+:=[0,\infty)$
$$ f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}_+$$
$$ n\mapsto f(n):={n}^{2}$$
and $\tau$,$\tau_1$,$\tau_2$ be the topologies defined as follows:
$$\tau :=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}_+ \}\cup \{[0,x):x\ge 0\}$$
$$\tau_1:=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{Z}\}\cup \{\{-n,-n+1,...,n-1,n\}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
$$\tau_2:=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{Z}\}\cup \{\{-n,-n+1,...,n-1,n\} \diagdown \{0\}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
Study the continuity of $f:(\mathbb{Z},\tau_i)\rightarrow(\mathbb{R}_+,\tau)$ for i=1,2

Sorry I am really not great on topology please help.

Comment: Please don't use `$$..$$` in the title. It breaks the front page.

Comment: sorry still getting used to the site :(

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: For any $x>0,$ $$\begin{align}f^{-1}\bigl([0,x)\bigr) &= \{k\in\Bbb Z:0\le f(k)<x\}\\ &= \{k\in\Bbb Z:0\le k^2<x\}\\ &= \{k\in\Bbb Z:k^2<x\}\\ &= \{k\in\Bbb Z:|k|<\sqrt{x}\}\\ &= \{k\in\Bbb Z:|k|<\lceil\sqrt{x}\rceil\}\\ &= \{k\in\Bbb Z:-\lceil\sqrt{x}\rceil<k<\lceil\sqrt{x}\rceil\}.\end{align}$$ Is this $\tau_1$-open? Is this $\tau_2$-open? (By "$\tau_i$-open," we mean "an element of $\tau_i$.")

As an aside, your definitions of $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ need a fix. Instead of "$n\in\Bbb Z$," we'll need $n\in\Bbb Z$ with $n\ge 1$" or perhaps "$n\in\Bbb Z$ with $n\ge 0$" for that to make sense.

Comment: I still don't really get this... I have been over this. What do I need to show?

Comment: In order for $f:(\Bbb Z,\tau_i)\to(\Bbb R_+,\tau)$ to be continuous, the preimage of every element of $\tau$ must be an element of $\tau_i$. What I've shown in my answer is what the preimages of the elements of $\tau$ look like. In particular, letting $m_x=\lceil\sqrt x\rceil$, we have $$f^{-1}\bigl([0,x)\bigr)=\begin{cases}\emptyset & m_x=0\\\{-m_x+1,...,m_x-1\} & m_x>0.\end{cases}$$ In which of the topologies will such sets always be open? Look at the definitions of $\tau_1,\tau_2$.

Comment: ok... do i need to do this for 0 to infinity as well, would $\tau_2$ not be continuous as  it doesn't include 0 and $\tau$ does?

Comment: Ah! An excellent question. As it turns out, no you don't, since for any function $g:A\to B$, we will always have $g^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ and $g^{-1}(B)=A$ by definition of preimage. (You should try to prove that, though.) What I *should* have said in that comment is that I've shown what the preimages of the *nontrivial* elements of $\tau$ look like.

Comment: And you're on the right track. None of the elements of $\tau_2$ contain $0$ as an element (save for $\Bbb Z$), but (for example), $$f^{-1}\bigl([0,1)\bigr)=\{0\},$$ so $f$ isn't continuous when $\Bbb R_+$ is considered under the topology $\tau_2$. What about $\tau_1$?

Comment: I thought it was continuous in $\tau_1$ as it includes 0

Comment: It is continuous in $\tau_1$, but isn't quite that simple. To prove it wasn't continuous in the other case, all we needed was a counterexample. To show continuity in this case, we actually need to show that those preimages I mentioned are all elements of $\tau_1.$

Comment: oh... topology is hard... how do you prove that?

Comment: Show that every one of those preimages I  mentioned is of the form $$\{-n,...,n\}$$ for some integer $n\ge0$.